# groupByKey transformation not working for Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to perform following operations but I am getting the error while using groupByKey transformation. I'm using Spark in standalone mode.

**sample.sbt** contains:

```
name := "Spark Join"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.0"

fork := true
```

**My Scala Code**

```
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import java.util.Properties

    object yelpDataJoin {
       def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val reviewFile = " /home/prasad/Desktop/BigData/psp150030_HW3/data/review3.csv"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJoins")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val reviewData = sc.textFile(reviewFile, 2)
    val groupReviewData = reviewData.map(line => line.split("::")).map(word => (word(2),(word(20),1))).groupByKey().foreach(println)
  }
}
```

I'm getting following error message:

```
15/07/20 16:10:48 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 32.0 KB, free 265.4 MB)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD$
    at yelpDataJoin$.main(HW3_Question2.scala:14)
    at yelpDataJoin.main(HW3_Question2.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 9 more
```

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong here.

Thanks & Regards,

Prasad

Comment: In other questions, this has often been a version conflict. Are you compiling with a different version than you're using to run the code?

Comment: Try to upgrade to Spark 1.4
I had similar issue, but it involved case classes. Didn't happen again when I upgraded.

Comment: @Paul My Spark Version is 1.1.0 as I can see from spark-shell. And the one mentioned in sample.sbt is 1.0 I tried to make it 1.1 but it does not change the output. I'm still getting the same output

Comment: So you submit using 1.1.0 and specify 1.3.0 as a dependency at the same time? Looks like [@Paul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/21755/paul) is right.

Comment: @Paul I got this. There was a version conflict When I changed the version in sample.sbt and packaged again using sbt package, it created a new jar file which should be referred while executing in standalone mode. In my case of was referring to the old jar. Thanks a lot for pointing out the issue.